# Why use Oracle version control?

Tags: oracle, version-control

At work we use Oracle (12c client) to store most of our data and I use SQL Developer to connect to the database environments.

### Issue:

We have issues where tables are being modified for one reason or another (too lazy to create a new table so they add new columns and change data types or lengths). This in return will break the table for others who actually utilize it for its real purpose.

**Update:**
We have DEV, TST, UAT, and PRD environments. We test and have scripts approved before we promote to PRD. The problem resides in DEV when we want to go back to an existing table to make an change, but that table had already been modified for different reasons.

### Question 1:

Is the versioning just for stored procedures or is it possible to track changes to table structures, functions, triggers, sequences, synonyms, etc.?

Comment: The company you work for needs to implement a change management strategy. Changes being made willy-nilly without thought as to downstream consequences is a recipe for disaster. You can raise the issue from your position, but you'll need to get management buy-in to ensure that implementation and enforcement takes place because this is really a management problem. Best of luck.

Comment: So you're saying using version control is pointless for this case?

Comment: Version control is part of the solution, but the major point is to get control of the process of installing changes. But version control by itself isn't particularly helpful. It may be nice to know that Fred, the whacko guy in the corner cubicle, made a change which caused significant negative impact, but if you can't prevent them from installing their change what have you gained? A process where Fred's manager needs to A) be informed of what's going on, and B) has to sign off on the change, and C) **is held responsible for the outcome** is more likely what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

As Bob Jarvis indicates you need way more than a solution to your question. You need policies and practices enforced for all developers. Some ideas from places I have worked:

- every developer has a VM machine with a copy of the database installed.  They can do whatever they like on it but must supply scripts to move their changes to production.  These scripts are applied on a test instance and again on a QA instance before going to production.
- subversion works on all OS and tortoise works well on windows. Committing scripts to a repository works well and this is integrated with SQL developer and can be done with Toad.
- you have a permissions issue.  Too many people have the privileges to alter tables.  Remove these permissions and centralize on one or two people.  Changes are funnelled through them as scripts and oversight can be applied there.  Developers can have their own schema to test or a VM with a copy for development.
- run this script to see who can alter tables

  select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS
  WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'ALTER'

The key is a separation of concerns.  Developers should have access to a schema where they can do what they need.  The company needs to know who did what, when and where.

If you have more than one developer working on multiple changes to a dev environment then you need coordination and communication as well as source control. A weekly meeting to discuss overlap areas or a heads up chat message are just some ways to work together.

Comment: I'm sure permissions has some to do with it, but currently we have DEV, TST, UAT, and PRD database environments and we promote our changes in PRD through testing/approving scripts. The issue resides with DEV. Tables, sequences, and the like get created, tested throughly, and then promoted. If we need to go back to make a change we change it in DEV, test it, and promote it. The issue is that when I want to go back to make a change, other changes had already been made. Thus, I need something like versioning if and only if it tracks changes made to tables, sequences, etc.

Comment: Or is there a way to allow only certain people to modify certain tables?

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr  See my point about permissions. Yes, you can set up grants and roles so only certain people can modify tables, see my edit

Comment: @NightOwlPrgmr You may think you only need to 'track changes made to tables, sequences' but really you need to track everything.  Databases are a point in time structure: Code, structure and data all change the behavior. Even data inserts need to be tracked and versioned.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I think works best, is to have a DEV database where all the developers manage their own set of schemas.

Scripted builds are provided with test data loads to allow any developer to create his own working schema. He then works on there, tests his changes and then commits his changes via scripts to the source control. DEV databases do not need to be large, just need enough test cases to allow for unit tests.

Script all the changes so that they can be checked into a version control system, and merged with other changes. The goal is to have a system where devA checks in changeA, and then when merged with the main trunk, devB gets changeA as he builds his schemaA.

This approach requires care if the main project schema employs PUBLIC synonyms. You will need to consider this as you go forward.

I would also advise with each change checked in an accompanying back out script should be checked in.

The advantage of this approach is that devs can manage their own schemas. With a scripted approach they dont all need to have DBA knowledge, and don't need to manage the database either. having all these on one database makes it easier to manage and control resources.

I've used this approach in teams with 50+ developers and it has worked very well.

This approach also paves the way for having devs checking scripts in and having a automatically creating a deployment package.

There is so much that can be done to make the development-test-deploy-backout cycle easier to manage.